# Calculation on previous dates in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the **age** for each day, but I need it for all previous dates in one query.

For example:

```
-- For SYDATE:
SELECT  SYSDATE AS DATE, 
((SYSDATE)- create_time) as Age
FROM items

-- For (SYDATE-1):
SELECT  (SYSDATE -1) AS DATE, 
((SYSDATE-1)- create_time) as Age
FROM items

-- For (SYDATE-2) AND SO ON ----:
SELECT  (SYSDATE-2) AS DATE,
((SYSDATE - 2)- create_time) as Age
FROM items
```

Is there any method so that it automatically calculates for previous dates and gives output.

Final output should display like this:

```
Date_in     Age
24/JUN/15   20
23/JUN/15   19
22/JUN/15   18
```

Comment: You might find this blogpost helpful: http://rwijk.blogspot.nl/2007/11/interval-based-row-generation.html

Comment: u can use lead(), lag() in window aggregation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the idea is to use an inline view that lists all the dates of the `items` table. I assume there is a creation_date every day.

Then use a cartesian product join with the items table.

You might need to filter more, not sure which result exactly you expect to have.

---

On [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5bbb0/10/0) I used this schema

```
CREATE TABLE items
( 
  item_id number,
  create_time date
);

insert into items values (1, sysdate-3);
insert into items values (2, sysdate-2);
insert into items values (3, sysdate-1);
insert into items values (4, sysdate);
```

to test this query, which might be what you were asking for

```
select 
b.system_date as date_in, (b.system_date-a.create_time) as age, a.item_id, a.create_time
from 
(select distinct create_time as system_date from items) b,
items a
order by date_in desc, age desc;
```

The result is available at the link above.

Comment: Hi Elyasin ,thanks for the idea but it's not just for 3 dates.it's for all the previous dates

Comment: What are the previous dates? You mean from today until the oldest create_time?

Comment: Can you guarantee that in the items table every day at least an item was created ?

Comment: yea Elyasin thanks for the logic,i will try it and update here whether it worked:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the Answer which worked for me:
select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 dt       
, trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date  age    from items  
connect by trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 - created_date > 0; 

or

SELECT  (SYSDATE-rownum) AS DATE,
((SYSDATE - rownum)- create_time)Age
FROM items
connect by level <3
```